# How to check whether a site has been compromised without browsing into it?

Tags: security, upgrade

I have been asked to take over an old and neglected Wordpress installation, which is still at version 3.4.2. I have read the upgrading instructions at:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions

...But I've got a problem in step 9, when it asks me to go with my browser to `/wp-admin/`.

Now, I have checked the site with Sucuri's scanner (https://sitecheck.sucuri.net) and found nothing, but at this point I'm treating the site as if it was a radioactive asset; in other words, I'm not getting anywhere near it with my browser unless I'm sure it doesn't have malware in it.

My plan at this point is to download a copy of the DB, open it with a text editor and check for anything weird: admin users that shouldn't be there, strange Javascript code in any posts or pages...I should probably also download an entire copy of it and check for hidden folders, strange plugins that shouldn't be there...

Is there anything else that I might look for? In other words, any way to check if the site has been compromised without actually browsing into it?

Comment: why do you ask here instead of in some security forum? It depends on the quality of the hacker, good ones will not be detected without comparing to previous good version.

Comment: Ummm... because this is a Wordpress site, and therefore people will have better specific knowledge of Wordpress? (Not just about its internals, but also about the most common attacks that people have seen in the wild). I have no expectations about being able to detect any NSA-grade exploit; I'm just looking for the most common ones, where people exploit a site and use it in turn to spread malware to its visitors, admins, etc., in order to build a botnet or whatever.

Comment: this is a wordpress development site. Hacking is **not** part of wordpress development and hacked site are explicitly off topic.

Comment: Why don't you use the incognito mode and browse the website? Online malwares are not as dangerous to your PC as exe files. If you have a security software installed such as kaspersky internet security, then all the better.

Comment: @JackJohansson, this is kinda weird suggestion. If he trusts the browser's security then there is no problem with accessing the site, and if hee doesn't then incognito mode make no difference as it is the same browser with the same security bugs.

Comment: @MarkKaplun There are some features that are disabled in incognito/private browsing to add some security layers. Also, IMO the modern browsers are smart enough these days not to allow script rookies to just slice through the security, especially when corporations like mozilla and google create a list of malicious websites and trigger a warning upon entrance. There was a time when you could steal a window's log-on key by js ( I still have the script ) but those don't work anymore.

Comment: @MarkKaplun By the way, he can access the website on a public computer, a phone, Live version of a linux, etc. There are hundreds of ways to browse the website without your sensitive data being damaged or your security exposed. I just don't see how browsing the website is the main issue here.

Comment: @JackJohansson exactly, the question itself do not make much sense, at least not in the way it is being phrased.... you can use internet explorer which you never use, install a new user on user PC etc etc etc.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Indeed. I'm also not sure, how can the OP debug the database to find the malware, if not able to browse the website safely. This requires more skill than just browsing it without being compromised.

Comment: @JackJohansson: just to clarify, I do have plenty of years of experience working with PHP and SQL databases, as well as reading MySQL dumps. I don't understand what you find so weird about it ;-)

Comment: As for "browsing the website", the main problem I have is that, judging from the online docs, upgrading WP always involves sooner or later having to browse into /wp-admin/. Weren't there examples of malware that served malicious code to WP admins when they logged into the site? I seem to remember it was a thing, years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the OP is asking for (IMHO) is a safe way to check for a hacked site **without** accessing the site, because OP is worried about putting the OP's system in a possible compromise.

My thought: download all of the files from the site to a local folder. Look at the local files for anything unusual (assuming you have knowledge of what you are looking at).

Or, you could upload a fresh/new version of WP to the site. Disable all plugins (quickly via FTP by just renaming the plugins folder to something else). Disable all non-standard themes by renaming those non-standard themes in the themes folder.

Take a look at the htaccess file for anything unusual; replace it with a default htaccess file.

You could do further testing on a local WAMP install with the code. But I think that the above will protect you sufficiently.

After you are comfortable with the site enough to login as admin, reinstall the latest WP version. Enable only those plugins that you are comfortable with. Enable any themes that you are comfortable with.

Change the database credentials also, and remove the user called 'admin' (after creating another admin-level user. Remove or disable any other user accounts until you can verify them as being valid.

Good luck.

Comment: this is like saying to someone that want to buy a used car "just take it for a neutral place and take a good look at it". Would you buy a car by just looking at it yourself, or will you go for a pro to get a professional opinion? Same thing here, if someone is not a security expert how will he know to identify anything wrong? It might even be that there is a problem in the server itself which will not be discovered in any of your steps.

Comment: The OP was not looking for a 'mechanic' to diagnose his site. He was looking for some guidance on things to look for. Which is what I advised, without judging his experience level. I stand by my answer, which may also help others if they stumble on to this question.

Comment: and your guidance unfortunately is not very good, as you didn't specify even one specific thing he should look for. The number of things that should be looked for should make an answer which is probably 3 times the length of yours, and since there is no such thing as "partially secure" the answer is far from being any good.

Comment: on second thought your answer is actually bad. assume there is a malware in the code. since usually local machine do not have privileges set properly the malware will have access to everything in his local machine and can damage it.

Comment: If there is malware code in the files, then an inspection of the files with an editor should allow him to find the problem; assuming (as I mentioned) that he has the knowledge to know what to look for. Any malware in the WP core code will be overwritten with a fresh local install of WP. Disabling all plugins should remove any threat of malware'd plugins. Using a 'twenty' theme should be OK, since the fresh install of WP should overwrite any malware possibility there. If he is super-paranoid, he could run site local without 'net connection. My suggestions should be OK to discern any problems.